# Dylib Error Message: library not loaded

Tags: macos

So I wrote an application, put it online and I have one user (for now) who tells me that the app doesn't run with the following error:

```
Dyld Error Message:
Library not loaded: @executable_path/../Frameworks/Users/tilmann/Documents/leksah/Macbeth/.cabal-sandbox/lib/x86_osx_ghc-7.8.3/wxc-0.92.1.1/libwxc.dylib
Referenced from: /Applications/Macbeth.app/Contents/MacOS/Macbeth
Reason: image not found
```

He tested on:

- MBA 2014 running ElCapitan
- MBP (i5, 2012) running Yosemite

The app icon only bounces and the app won't start on both systems.

So I checked:

- The library is at the specified path.
- otool -L confirms the specified path.

Then I tested on:

- MBA 2012 with OSX 10.9.5
- MBA 2012 with ElCapitan using VirtualBox
- on unspecified MBP with El Capitan from friends
  ... and it would always start!

So I'm writing emails back and forth with my user, who is so kind to help me try fix this, but now I just don't know what to do any more. Maybe you have a suggestion what I could ask about his system that might be different and cause this behaviour. Any help is really appreciated!

(If you want to try for yourself, please have a look at http://www.macbeth-ficsclient.com/)

Comment: I'm not surprised; that path is totally broken.

Comment: Sorry, I posted the error from an older version. Now the path is: @executable_path/../Frameworks/Users/tilmann/Documents/leksah/Macbeth/.cabal-sandbox/lib/x86_64-osx-ghc-7.10.2/wxc-0.92.2.0-LuIbbYNJNYCIe1UVH1LleT/libwxc.dylib

Comment: And that looks OK to you?

Comment: that's the path that otool -L gives me. What don't I see?

Comment: You don't see what it means.  That is the path from the executable to the dylib (where `@executable_path` is the starting point).  Now if you go into the app bundle and look at the structure you will see that it *should* be just `@executable_path/../Frameworks`.  So something is broken in your build.

Comment: Oh, I think that shouldn't be the problem. libwxc.dylib is really in that directory, relative to the executable, put in there by the build process. And otool shows me that the path is know to the app.

Comment: *pantomime voice* Oh yes it is.  The linker never lies...

Comment: I hope he doesn't lie. Or does he, maybe sometimes? I'm really lost.. (Did you try run the program?)

Comment: No, it's incapable of lying.  If a human is involved in the process then it's always them at fault (you, that is).  To test: Fire up Terminal.app, change to the app bundle folder inside your *Derived Data*, go into the `Contents/MacOS` folder (which contains the executable) and see what `ls -l ../Frameworks/Users/tilmann/Documents/leksah/Macbeth/.cabal-san‌​dbox/lib/x86_64-osx-ghc-7.10.2/wxc-0.92.2.0-LuIbbYNJNYCIe1UVH1LleT/libwxc.dylib` gives you.

Comment: So, now the mystery remains. How is it then possible that the app won't start on some systems? Any idea?

Comment: Thank you btw for taking time!

Comment: ls -l produces: -rw-r--r--@ 1 tilmann  admin  1759828  4 Apr 19:10 ... Maybe @ causes problems?

Comment: You need to carefully read what I wrote.  It was the full path without the leading `@executable_path`.

Comment: Yes, sure. I did `cd /Applications/Macbeth.app/Contents/MacOS` followed by `ls -l ../Frameworks/Users/tilmann/Documents/...`. I was refering to the @ as part of the result of ls -l.

Comment: Oh; that means it's a symbolic link doesn't it?  You'd have to show the complete line, but it likely points outside of the app bundle and would therefore be unavailable on the user's system.

Comment: actually, it means that there are extended attributes attached to the file and possibly Access Control Lists (ACL)

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/42177/what-does-signify-in-unix-file-permissions